# In SQL how do I query three different tables and find the one that has a value when the others are NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, subquery

Hi all I wonder if someone can help me with an SQL problem. We have a database containing all our printers and their related settings. As we have three generations of printers settings were placed in different tables linked to the master table by the serial number.  each setting is also given a different name as a naming convention wasn't agreed. As an example Im looking at the Start Setting

**Table 1 - dbo.Base**
Master table containing all printer serials and the settings for gen 1

**Table 2 - dbo.RioPro360**
Gen 2 printer settings linked by serial

**Table 3 - dbo.HelicalData**
Gen 3 printer settings linked by serial

Each table uses the serial number as a unique ID

As a test query I can run the following

```
    SELECT
    LTRIM(RTRIM(UPPER(a.SerialNo))) AS [ID],
    LTRIM(RTRIM(UPPER(a.SerialNo))) AS [Name],
    ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(a.ImageStart)),'NULL') AS [Start A],
    ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(b.PrintImageStart)),'NULL') [Start B],
    ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(c.TransferStartOffset)),'NULL') AS [Start C]
FROM SAP_RIOTANGO.dbo.Base AS a
LEFT JOIN SAP_RIOTANGO.dbo.RioPro360 AS b ON b.IdPrinterSerial = a.SerialNo
LEFT JOIN SAP_RIOTANGO.dbo.HelicalData AS c ON c.printerSerial = a.SerialNo
WHERE a.SerialNo = '73F3939' OR  a.SerialNo = '66717401' OR  a.SerialNo = '58905701'
```

**Result**

```
+----------+----------+---------+--------+---------+
|    ID    |  SERIAL  | START A | STAR B | START C |
+----------+----------+---------+--------+---------+
| 66717401 | 66717401 | NULL    | 1200   | NULL    |
| 73F3939  | 73F3939  | -115    | NULL   | NULL    |
| 58905701 | 58905701 | NULL    | NULL   | 21      |
+----------+----------+---------+--------+---------+
```

this gives me the start setting for each printer from the table that has a value. What I need to do is combine the starts into one column

**Required result**

```
+----------+----------+-------+
|    ID    |  SERIAL  | START |
+----------+----------+-------+
| 66717401 | 66717401 |  1200 |
| 73F3939  | 73F3939  |  -115 |
| 58905701 | 58905701 |    21 |
+----------+----------+-------+
```

I was thinking of creating a temporary table and running a sub query if a field is null but cant get it to work and wandered if anyone could help me get this to return what I want

Comment: Do you understand the difference between using the string NULL in your query and how an actual NULL value is displayed in an application (like SSMS)? Using the string NULL as you did can cause implicit conversion - which can lead to errors. Be careful about using isnull like this. And why do you trim the values in your column? Especially if those values appear to be numbers? Know your datatypes, avoid implicit conversion, don't create unnecessary work for the database engine.

Comment: Hi SMor I asked that exact same questions to the developer who designed the database regarding the trims and NULL values but just got told its how we want it. the TRIMS are there as the production line entry point has in the past placed spaces  before and after the string the field is not a number as a serial is a collection of alpha numeric values was just the three examples i tested were all numeric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `COALESCE()`:

```
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(UPPER(a.SerialNo))) AS [ID],
       LTRIM(RTRIM(UPPER(a.SerialNo))) AS [Name],
       COALESCE(LTRIM(RTRIM(a.ImageStart)),
                LTRIM(RTRIM(b.PrintImageStart)),
                LTRIM(RTRIM(c.TransferStartOffset))
               ) as [Start]
```

Comment: thanks @Gordon Linoff thats working great but now have a problem with getting latest records but will create a new question for this